# Visual Studio return result and wsdl type not match

Tags: web-services, wcf, soap-client

Hi I import  wsdl into myvisual studio project but incoming message type and resulttype are not match each other.And result cannot be deserialized.

But When I try that wsdl with SoapUI ,there is no problem
on the other hand I use visual studio that time problem matching type

Is there any suggestion about this topic

Comment: is the response coming back, i.e. can you see it in fiddler or system diagnostice tracing, but when your code tries to deserialize it, it ends up null?

Comment: yes response is coming back I see in trace logs of wcf

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem before, it had to do with the way that svcutil.exe was generating the DataContracts for the Operations.

In my client side Interface (reference.vb or .cs if C#, unless you use svcutil via command line to generate your proxy class), I had to set the reply action from:

```
<System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action:="", ReplyAction:="*")
```

to the actual action or at least what I thought it was, `http://tempuri.org/MyInterfaceName/MyMethodName`

```
<System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action:="", ReplyAction:="http://tempuri.org/MyInterfaceName/MyMethodName")
```

Then I had to remove the XmlTypeAttribute from the response class, the object being sent back to the client:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=true, [Namespace]:="https://example.com?wsdl")>
```

As well as remove the XmlElementAttributes from the properties in the response class:

```
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order:=0)>
```

Not sure if this will apply to your scenario, but I am quite sure your issue has something to do with they way the datacontracts are formatted by VS.